# How to pass value of a id to a function when I drag a DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, drag

This is my Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".ex" ).draggable({containment:'parent',cursor:'pointer',opacity:0.6,




 stop : function () {
           var x = $(this).position().left;
           var y = $(this).position().top;

             $.ajax({
    url: "savedrag.php", /* You need to enter the URL of your server side script*/
    type: "POST",
      /* add the other variables here or serialize the entire form. 
      Image data must be URI encoded */
    data:{
            x: x,
            y: y
            },  
    success: function(msg)
    {
       alert("position save");
    }

        })
       } 
});

});
```

this is my PHP

```
   <?php

$qry = "SELECT * from contact Where CustomerID='$pid'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{

 echo '<div class="ex">';
 $row["ContactID"];
 echo '</div>';

}


?>
```

How can I pass in variable $row["ContactID"] into each function, so that each draggable div have their own indivdual position in the database?

Previvously I pass in value through button using onclick(this); but I cannot do the same for draggable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this:
Javascript addition:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");

//...

data:{
    x: x,
    y: y,
    id: id
}
```

php :

```
 echo '<div class="ex" id="$row["ContactID"];">'; 
 echo '</div>';
```

Comment: I cannot get the id with "var id = $(this).attr("id");"

Comment: do I have to place it inside draggable function?

Answer (score 1):

With the given markup, you can

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ex").draggable({
        containment : 'parent',
        cursor : 'pointer',
        opacity : 0.6,

        stop : function() {
            var x = $(this).position().left;
            var y = $(this).position().top;

            $.ajax({
                url : "savedrag.php", 
                type : "POST",
                data : {
                    x : x,
                    y : y,
                    ContactID: $.trim($(this).html())
                },
                success : function(msg) {
                    alert("position save");
                }

            })
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: @Ryan the you can add it as an attribute of the `div`. ex `<div class="ex" ContactID="$row["ContactID"];">`, then in js `$(this).attr('ContactID')` will give you the value. *Discalimer: Not sure about the PHP syntax*